# Upgrade kernel linux with apt-get

Tags: kernel, upgrade, apt

I'm using these commands to upgrade the kernel version in Ubuntu 14.04:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-3.13.11-bone12 linux-image-3.13.11-bone12 --fix-missing -y
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade --fix-missing -y
sudo reboot
```

But, after rebooting, the kernel version continues to be the same.

Does anybody know what is wrong?

Any tip will be very helpful,

Thanks

Comment: Did you update your bootloader by doing `sudo update-grub` and `sudo update-initramfs -u`? (but I guess that should have been done automatically..) What kernel versions do you see in the bootloader menu?

Comment: Thanks! I'll try these commands. I see the 3.12.10 version.